# convenient "chained" || (OR) expressions in liquid

Tags: javascript, jekyll, liquid

In javascript, I can write something like this

```
console.log( person.name || person.nickname || '-' )
```

and it will first look for the `name` field, and if it can't find it, it will fallback to the `nickname` field, and if it can't find that, it will finally fallback to a `-` placeholder.

Is there any nice/convenient syntax to do this in liquid? That is, is there any way to do it in a single line, without a bunch of `if`/`elseifs`.

Comment: I reckon you'd need to use the `or` operator.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, I've tried. The `or` operator seems to only be valid in a logical condition (ie `{% if conditionA == true or conditionB == false %}`), but what I really need it in is in an "expression"  that gets evaluated and put in place (ie `{{ variable }}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly not. Although you can use 'or' in liquid logic, writing 'or' between double curly brackets is not allowed. You will get the following error:

> Expected end_of_string but found id in "{{ person.name or person.nickname or '-' }}" in /path/to/page

I think that the shortest way to write this, is:

`{{ person.name }}{% unless person.name %}{{ person.nickname }}{% unless person.nickname %}-{% endunless %}{% endunless %}`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks. The `unless` syntax luckily isn't super bad. Nor is the `elsif`.